# How do you write a repository query in Spring boot to filter by an association key?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, repository

How do you write a query in a repository interface to do a WHERE assoc_id = :key?

I have an entity called `CmsImpacts`, and then I have a service that calls the `ImpactsRepository` which looks like this:

```java
    import java.util.List;
    
    public interface ImpactsRepository<T extends CmsImpacts> extends BaseCmsRepository<CmsImpacts> {
        
        @Query("SELECT a FROM #{#entityName} a where a.scenarioId = :scenarioId")
        List<CmsImpacts> getByScenarioPaged(
                Integer scenarioId,
                Pageable pageable
        );
        
        @Query("SELECT COUNT(a.id) FROM #{#entityName} a where a.scenarioId = :scenarioId")
        Integer getAsScenarioCount(
                Integer scenarioId
        );
        
        
        
    }
```

The gist of this relationship is that `CmsScenarios` is a one to many on `CmsImpacts`. The entity relation is defined as:

```java
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "scenario_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private CmsScenarios scenarioId;
```

Whenever I call my service and pass in the Integer value of the scenario_id, it throws a TypeException because (rightfully so), expects a CmsScenario object, not an Integer.

**Error Message**: 2020-11-04 15:10:45.764 ERROR 128396 --- [io-8080-exec-18] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/api/impacts/list/scenario/2] due to exception [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [2] did not match expected type [com.vw.asa.entities.cms.CmsScenarios (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2] did not match expected type [com.vw.asa.entities.cms.CmsScenarios (n/a)]]

What do I need to do in order to execute this query? This applies to the query above it also, the Paginated counter.

**Note:**

I do not want to just retrieve the `CmsScenarios` object and call `getImpacts()`, that would return all objects, and I need to be able to paginate over them.

Comment: Can you try a.scenarioId.id in place of a.scenarioId in your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the id of the related entity

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM #{#entityName} a where a.scenarioId.id = :scenarioId")
```